# Why is the "data" parameter in my gridOptions (ng-grid) always empty?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc

This command...i.e.,

```
    $http.get('http://localhost:8084/nggridtest/tasks')
    .success(function (data) 
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.tasks = data;  // <=== not working???
    });
```

... appears to successfully retrieve data - as shown by my alert...i.e.,

[image]

However, it appears that the command - `$scope.tasks = data;` - does not appear assign the data to my "$scope.tasks" variable - resulting in an empty grid... i.e.,

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

### Update

Below is more information.

***app.js***

```
    /* global angular */
    var taskApp = angular.module('taskApp', ['ngGrid']);

    var taskController = taskApp.controller('taskController', function taskController($scope, $http) 
    {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8084/nggridtest/tasks')
            .success(function (data) 
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.tasks = data;
            });

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'tasks',
            columnDefs: [
                {field: 'taskId', displayName: 'taskId'},
                {field: 'taskName', displayName: 'taskName'},
                {field: 'taskDescription', displayName: 'taskDescription'},
                {field: 'taskStartTime', displayName: 'taskStartTime'},
                {field: 'taskEndTime', displayName: 'taskEndTime'},
                {field: 'taskArchived', displayName: 'taskArchived'}
            ]
        };
    });
```

***app.css***

```
    .gridStyle
    {
        margin: 0;
        width:100em;
        height:50em;
    }
```

***index.jsp***

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="taskApp">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Spring MVC, REST, AngularJS testing</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.css" media="screen">         
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/ng-grid/2.0.14/ng-grid.css" media="screen"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.css" media="screen"/>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/ng-grid/2.0.14/ng-grid.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>        
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-controller="taskController">
                <div class='panel panel-primary row container-fluid' style="margin: 2em; padding:0;">
                    <div class='panel-heading' style="margin: 0;">
                        <h1 class='panel-title'>Entries</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-body' style="padding:0;">  
                        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
                    </div>                          
                </div>                
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

***TaskController.java***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @RestController
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class TaskController
    {
        private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("TaskController");

        TaskService taskmanagerservice = new TaskService();

        @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
        public List<Task> getAllTasks()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = null;

            try
            {
                tasks = taskmanagerservice.getAllTasks();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LOG.error("____________________________getAllTasks____________________________Exception encountered - e.getMessage=" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return tasks;
        }
    }
```

***TaskService.java***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

    public class TaskService
    {
        private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("TaskService");

        private Connection connection;

        public TaskService()
        {
            connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
        }

        public List<Task> getAllTasks()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = null;

            try
            {
                tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from task_list where task_archived=false");
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Task task = new Task();
                    task.setTaskId(rs.getInt("task_id"));
                    task.setTaskName(rs.getString("task_name"));
                    task.setTaskDescription(rs.getString("task_description"));
                    task.setTaskPriority(rs.getString("task_priority"));
                    task.setTaskStatus(rs.getString("task_status"));
                    tasks.add(task);
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                LOG.error("____________________________getAllTasks____________________________Exception encountered - e.getMessage=" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return tasks;
        }
    }
```

***DBUtility***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

    public class DBUtility
    {
        private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("DBUtility");
        private static Connection connection = null;

        public static Connection getConnection()
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                return connection;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Properties prop = new Properties();
                    InputStream inputStream = DBUtility.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
                    prop.load(inputStream);
                    String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
                    String url = prop.getProperty("url");
                    String user = prop.getProperty("user");
                    String password = prop.getProperty("password");
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    LOG.error("____________________________getConnection____________________________ClassNotFoundException", e);
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    LOG.error("____________________________getConnection____________________________SQLException", e);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    LOG.error("____________________________getConnection____________________________FileNotFoundException", e);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    LOG.error("____________________________getConnection____________________________IOException", e);
                }

                return connection;
            }
        }
    }
```

***Task.java***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    public class Task
    {
        private int task_id;
        private String task_name;
        private String task_description;
        private String task_priority;
        private String task_status;

        public int getTaskId()
        {
            return task_id;
        }
        public void setTaskId(int taskId)
        {
            this.task_id = taskId;
        }

        public String getTaskName()
        {
            return task_name;
        }
        public void setTaskName(String taskName)
        {
            this.task_name = taskName;
        }

        public String getTaskDescription()
        {
            return task_description;
        }
        public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription)
        {
            this.task_description = taskDescription;
        }

        public String getTaskPriority()
        {
            return task_priority;
        }
        public void setTaskPriority(String taskPriority)
        {
            this.task_priority = taskPriority;
        }

        public String getTaskStatus()
        {
            return task_status;
        }
        public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus)
        {
            this.task_status = taskStatus;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Task{" + "task_id=" + task_id + ", task_name=" + task_name + ", task_description=" + task_description + ", task_priority=" + task_priority + ", task_status=" + task_status + '}';
        }
    }
```

***applicationContext.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.bbb.ccc.war" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            </mvc:message-converters>
        </mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"> 
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/> 
            <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" /> 
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
        </bean>    
        <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    
    </beans>
```

***web.xml***

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">
        <filter>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>    
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml           
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

***config.properties***

```
    driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/taskmanager
    user=app
    password=app
```

***log4j2.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="warn" name="testLogEvent" packages="">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
               <PatternLayout pattern="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>           
           </Console>
            <!-- writes log file to the tomee "logs" folder... -->       
            <File name="appLog" fileName="../logs/nggridtest.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n</Pattern>                
                </PatternLayout>
            </File>
            <Async name="Async">
                <AppenderRef ref="appLog"/>
            </Async>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="DEBUG">
                <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>  
                <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>                      
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

***used derby database***

```
    CREATE TABLE "TASK_LIST"
    (    
       "TASK_ID" INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),   
       "TASK_NAME" VARCHAR(50),     
       "TASK_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR(50),
       "TASK_PRIORITY" VARCHAR(100),
       "TASK_STATUS" VARCHAR(20),
       "TASK_START_TIME" TIMESTAMP,  
       "TASK_END_TIME" TIMESTAMP,
       "TASK_ARCHIVED" BOOLEAN 
    );

    //...NOTE: the task_id column value is auto-generated...
    insert into task_list (task_name, task_description, task_priority, task_status, task_start_time, task_end_time, task_archived) values('Gathering Requirement',    'Requirement Gathering',    'MEDIUM',   'ACTIVE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_HOUR, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}, false);
    insert into task_list (task_name, task_description, task_priority, task_status, task_start_time, task_end_time, task_archived) values('Application Designing',    'Application Designing',    'MEDIUM',   'ACTIVE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_HOUR, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}, false);
    insert into task_list (task_name, task_description, task_priority, task_status, task_start_time, task_end_time, task_archived) values('Implementation',           'Implementation',           'MEDIUM',   'ACTIVE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_HOUR, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}, false);
    insert into task_list (task_name, task_description, task_priority, task_status, task_start_time, task_end_time, task_archived) values('Unit Testing',             'Unit Testing',             'LOW',      'ACTIVE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_HOUR, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}, false);
    insert into task_list (task_name, task_description, task_priority, task_status, task_start_time, task_end_time, task_archived) values('Maintenance',              'Maintenance',              'LOW',      'ACTIVE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_HOUR, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}, false);
```

***PROJECT STRUCTURE***

[image]

Comment: I never tried to use ng-grid, but as someone who has had similar issues with angular, the likely issue is that $scope.tasks is not defined when ng-grid is initialized. Just hardcode the value for $scope.tasks to see if this is the cause, if so should be straightforward to fix from there. Also, you dont need to include all the server side java files here, just makes it harder for people to read and understand your question.

Comment: Question: Did you try replacing $scope.tasks = data; with $scope.tasks = JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: LOL i had to do a double take as I misread that url as some sort of really racist test for voter id.

Comment: FWIW - I tried changing from "$scope.tasks = data;"  to  "$scope.tasks = JSON.stringify(data);"  did not work.

Comment: Could you please try with static response like as below 

$scope.tasks = [{taskName: "Moroni", taskId: 50},
                     {taskName: "Tiancum", taskId: 43},
                     {taskName: "Jacob", taskId: 27},
                     {taskName: "Nephi", taskId: 29},
                     {taskName: "Enos", taskId: 34}];

Comment: Absolutely will try that and then let you know.  (Though, it will be Monday a.m., at the earliest).  Thank you,  Hrishi.   (I've had no luck with the other suggestions that were kindly submiited, unfortunately)

Comment: Thank you all for your input/suggestions.   It seems I couldn't see the forest for the trees.   The issue was rooted in css.    When I failed to see output, I assumed it was some mistake with my angular syntax, etc.,  and I unsystematically wasted hours troubleshooting (changing code, etc)  from that narrow perspective.  But, the root cause was my css link path used "/js/" instead of "/css/" which resulted in a collapsed '<div>'.  My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

As Lrossy mentioned, it could be that the object has not been defined yet. so at the beginning of your controller or link function (before the get request), define it:

`$scope.tasks = []`

then, perhaps it needs a nudge to apply the scope? Not likely since $http knows to do this, but it may help to put this in your success handler:

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, FlavorScape.   -Didn't seem to make a diiference, however.